# How can I create a tile with different colors under headings and under paragraphs?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and trying to experiment with it a bit, so that I can start making up a page without accumulating bad code due to inexperience.

In the following snippet I code a panel/tile with a think black border and the top, a light grey background. The whole `.tile` class is given some padding (`1em`), which is nice.

But suppose I want to give more "color" by using a darker grey beneath `h2` and `h5` ***for the whole length of the tile***, like this
[image]

How should I go about it?

I'd rether avoid negative margins/padding or other trick-like things to accompish the task, *if possible*.

```css
/* stuff I always put */
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
}
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
body * + * {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

/* for demo only */
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
}

/* stuff for the question */
.tile {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: .5em 0 0 0;
  background-color: hsl(0,0%,90%);
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <h5>Long subtitle here</h5>
  <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
  labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: **But suppose I want to give more "color" by using a darker grey beneath h2 and h5 for the whole length of the tile. How should I go about it?** Do you mean something like `h2, h5 { color: darkgrey; }`?

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99, probably you meant `background-color`? However, I'll explain better in a moment.

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99, how is it now?

Comment: why dont you remove your padding on the parent and specify it on the children directly ? as I made below ?

Comment: Is your problem background color not extending to parents padding?

Comment: why don't you want to use negative margin values?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov because it couples two unrelated things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be an easier / cleaner way to manage it block by block.

You should use `rem` instead of `em` to specify the place of your block. Indeed, while `rem` size is based on the `html` size, `em` is based on the parent size.

Example:

```css
html, body{
  font-size: 16px ;
}

#parent-1, #parent-2{
  background:red;
}
#parent-1 h1, #parent-2 h1{
  background: grey;
}

#parent-1{
  font-size:60px;
}
#parent-1 h1{
  font-size:0.5em; /* So equal to 30px */
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin: 1em;
}

#parent-2{
  font-size:60px;
}
#parent-2 h1{
  font-size:.5rem;  /* So equal to 8px */
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-1">
  <h1>I am with EM</h1>
</div>

<div id="parent-2">
  <h1>I am with REM</h1>
</div>
```

### DEMO

```css
/* stuff I always put */
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
}
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
body * + * {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

/* for demo only */
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
}

/* stuff for the question */
.tile {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: .5em 0 0 0;
  background-color: hsl(0,0%,90%);
  /*padding: 1em;*/
}
h2, h5{
  background-color: grey;
  margin:0;
}
h2, h5, p{
  padding:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <h5>Long subtitle here</h5>
  <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
  labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, so you're using `rem`s for the padding instead of `em`s so that the same value is computed for the `h2`, `h5`, and `p`.

Comment: yes because if you use `em` it would not be possible to reach the same padding. Hope it helps you

Comment: So probably in this case, while still using `rem`s as you suggest, I could do so for lateral padding, but keep using `em`s for vertical padding. This is just my attempt to stick, if possible, to what Keith Grant suggests in [his book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32171114-css-in-depth).

Comment: Indeed, you could apply `padding: 1em 1rem;` for example that you would fit but the problem. is that you would multiply padding for each child. So space can increase fast between elements.

Comment: You still apply padding vertical to parent and apply padding horizontal for children

Comment: In that book the authors warns about `em`s for font size for the reason you mention (multiplication across the hierarchy) and suggests to use `rem`s instead. But are talking of padding. Can you please spend some word in the answer? I'm not sure I've understood what the impact would, nor if you are alluding to a bad impact of `em`s or `rem`s in this case.

Comment: Here I added an example, but I am sure you can find more